# Angular2Mvc5Application template issue

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

Recently I installed visual studio 2015 and I started my new project with Angular2Mvc5Application template, as soon as template was installed I notice there are 60 errors

[image]

How to solve this issue / or is there a simple working template with sample application in angular 2.0. for .Net MVC ?

Answer (score 0):

run `npm install` on your root where package.json is located. This will restore your dependencies.